# Aggregation function with condition in partition clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I had this following table in SQL Server:

| colA | colB | colC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | -1 |
| a1 | 2 | -1 |
| a1 | 3 | 12 |
| a1 | 4 | 2 |
| a1 | 5 | -45 |

I want to calculate the cumulative sum for col C only in the case of positive result else 0

```
select *
    , sum(colC) over (partition by colA order by colB asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as colD
from tableA
```

If I am using above query it is resulted as:

| colA | colB | colC | colD | . |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | -1 | -1 | -1 = -1 |
| a1 | 2 | -1 | -2 | -1 + -1 = -2 |
| a1 | 3 | 12 | 10 | -2 + 12 = 10 |
| a1 | 4 | 2 | 12 | 10 + 2 = 12 |
| a1 | 5 | -45 | -33 | 12 + -45 = -33 |

but what I want is:

| colA | colB | colC | colD | . |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | -1 | 0 | -1 = -1 (-1 is negative so I want 0) |
| a1 | 2 | -1 | 0 | 0 + -1 = -1 (-1 is negative so I want 0) |
| a1 | 3 | 12 | 12 | 0 + 12 = 12 |
| a1 | 4 | 2 | 14 | 12 + 2 = 14 |
| a1 | 5 | -45 | 0 | 14 + -45 = -31 (-31 is negative so I want 0) |

How can I achieve this in SQL query?

Comment: This is actually a hard problem. But lucky for you there is an answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/178152/set-non-negative-floor-for-rolling-sum-in-sql-server). Its not going to perform well either since you have to use a recursive solution.

Comment: What happens if the next value is `31`, do you want `0` or `31`? In other words, once you go negative and therefore return `0`, do you care about what the previous row's exact value was?

Comment: In that case i want 31 because previous result 0 + next value is 31 = 31

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go for a derived table and apply CASE expression as given below:

```sql
declare @t table( colA  char(2), colB   int, colC int)

insert into @t 
values
('a1',1     ,-1 )  
,('a1',2    ,-1 )
,('a1',3    ,12 )
,('a1',4    ,2)
,('a1',5    ,-45);


;with cte_colD as
(
SELECT colA,colB,ColC, CASE WHEN colc < 0 then 0 else colC end as ColD
from @t
where colB =1 
union all
SELECT t.colA,t.colB,t.ColC, CASE WHEN (c.colD + t.colC) <0 then 0 else (c.colD + t.colC) end as ColD
from @t as t
INNER JOIN cte_colD as c
on t.colA = c.colA
and t.colB = c.colB + 1
)
select * from cte_colD
```

| colA | colB | ColC | ColD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | -1 | 0 |
| a1 | 2 | -1 | 0 |
| a1 | 3 | 12 | 12 |
| a1 | 4 | 2 | 14 |
| a1 | 5 | -45 | 0 |

Comment: For row number 3 result it should be 12 because previous result 0 + next value 12 = 12 , similar for row number 4 previous result 12 + next value 2 = 14

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table( colA  varchar(50), colB   int, colC int)

insert into @t 
values
('a1',1     ,-1 )  
,('a1',2    ,-1 )
,('a1',3    ,12 )
,('a1',4    ,2)
,('a1',5    ,-45);

with t as (
select colA,colB,ColC
,sum(IIF(ColC < 0,0,ColC)) over (partition by colA order by colB asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as colD
FROM @t)

select colA,colB,ColC,
IIF(ColC<0,0,ColD) ColD
from t
order by colB
```